# How to create a new wordpress page programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in wordpress.
I am unable to find a way to create a new wordpress page using plugin.
I want to make a new page on the front end of the wordpress when the user activates the plugin.

Answer (score 17):

With the help of above code, you can create dynamic page.
 Firstly we need to check if the post we are going to create is available or not.
 If present you dont need to create another one you can edit the content of the 
 page. But if you changed the title of the page new page will be created.
 Here I have created a page with the help of title of the page.

```
$check_page_exist = get_page_by_title('title_of_the_page', 'OBJECT', 'page');
// Check if the page already exists
if(empty($check_page_exist)) {
    $page_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
        'comment_status' => 'close',
        'ping_status'    => 'close',
        'post_author'    => 1,
        'post_title'     => ucwords('title_of_the_page'),
        'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('title_of_the_page'))),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_content'   => 'Content of the page',
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'post_parent'    => 'id_of_the_parent_page_if_it_available'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: replace: ` 'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('title_of_the_page'))), `
with: ` 'post_name'      => sanitize_title('title_of_the_page'), ` <-- uses Wordpress function
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/

Answer (score 11):

Something like this

```
function some_function()
{
   $post_details = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Page title',
  'post_content'  => 'Content of your page',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_type' => 'page'
   );
   wp_insert_post( $post_details );
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'some_function');
```

See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) for other possible params.

Comment: thanks alot it worked :)
what if i want dynamic content..i mean the content will change every day through the database. while here under the "post_content" index we are giving a static data

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you could explain in more details? If you want to change content, update created page when you need I guess(ID of it is returned by wp_insert_post).

Comment: under the post_content index of $post_details we are giving a static value which is "Content of your page" .Now my question is how i can edit that value again? for example i want to update the page with this value"<p>This is a simple paragraph.</p>"

Comment: Like so `$post_details = array(
      'ID'           => $id,  'post_content' => '<p>This is a simple paragraph.</p>',
  );
  wp_update_post( $post_details );` You can get ID of newly created page from wp_insert_post like so `$id=wp_insert_post( $post_details );`

Comment: ok thanks alot :)

and where can i find the id of that page in my database?

Comment: You could store it as an option on activation_hook I guess. Then get it from there when needed.

Comment: you mean to save the id in the database? and then call it when needed to update the content of the page....is there any else solution because i would have to create a new database table for just one id

Comment: You don't need to create a table. You can do `update_option( 'my_option_key', $id );` on activation hook, and then `get_option('my_option_key')` to get that ID when you it. Also, you should check if this option exists before creating page (to prevent multiple page creations upon multiple activations)

Comment: Also, please accept answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 11):

A convenient helper function to create a bunch of pages:

```
function create_page($title_of_the_page,$content,$parent_id = NULL ) 
{
    $objPage = get_page_by_title($title_of_the_page, 'OBJECT', 'page');
    if( ! empty( $objPage ) )
    {
        echo "Page already exists:" . $title_of_the_page . "<br/>";
        return $objPage->ID;
    }
    
    $page_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
            'comment_status' => 'close',
            'ping_status'    => 'close',
            'post_author'    => 1,
            'post_title'     => ucwords($title_of_the_page),
            'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim($title_of_the_page))),
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_content'   => $content,
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'post_parent'    =>  $parent_id //'id_of_the_parent_page_if_it_available'
            )
        );
    echo "Created page_id=". $page_id." for page '".$title_of_the_page. "'<br/>";
    return $page_id;
}

create_page( 'How it works', 'This is how it works');
create_page( 'Contact Us', 'The contact us page');
create_page( 'About Us', 'The about us page');
create_page( 'Team', 'The team page');
$pid = create_page( 'Sample Page', 'This is sample page');
create_page( 'Sample SubPage 1', 'This is sample SubPage 1',$pid);
create_page( 'Sample SubPage 2', 'This is sample SubPage 2',$pid);
```

Answer (score 5):

This way you can add page

```
// Create post object
 $my_post = array(
   'post_type'     => 'page',
   'post_title'    => 'My post',
   'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
   'post_status'   => 'publish',
   'post_author'   => 1
 );

 // Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

For detail see this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: This will insert a post, not a page. You need to specify the `post_type` as "page".